# Openid not working in OSQA hosted on hostgator

Tags: python, openid, osqa

I have installed osqa on server hosted on hostgator. Openid is not working at all.
When I click on google under login I get a **Page not found (404)** error.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

[as you noted](http://meta.osqa.net/question/1961/openid-not-working-in-osqa-hosted-on-hostgator) in your comment on a similar question at http://meta.osqa.net this was a problem with some whitelist issue between Google and hostgator, and apparently they have resolved it. As far as we know, the [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net) openid support works beautifully, and this issue was entirely on the hostgator side.